# Live email validation by jQuery is not working, I can not find the bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, live

here is the code, I can not find the bug. The background images are coming from a local directory, the same with jQuery library. I have tested the paths and they are all fine. Somehow something is not working and I can not find out.

```
<html>
    <head>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/myform/js/jquery.js"></script>    
        <script type="text/javascript"> 

            function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
                var pattern = new RegExp(/^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@([\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]+$/);
                return pattern.test(emailAddress);
            }

            $(document).ready(function() {
                 
                $("#validate").keyup(function(){
                    var email = $("#validate").val();
                     
                    if(email != 0)
                    {
                        if(isValidEmailAddress(email))
                        {
                             
                            $("#validEmail").css({ "background-image": "url('/myform/logos/validyes.png')" });
                         
                        } else {
                             
                            $("#validEmail").css({ "background-image": "url('/myform/logos/validno.png')" });
                         
                        }
                     
                    } else {
                         
                        $("#validEmail").css({ "background-image": "none" });
                     
                    }
                });
            });

        </script>
            <style>
            #validEmail
            {
                margin-top: 4px;
                margin-left: 9px;
                position: absolute;
                width: 16px;
                height: 16px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>


        <div><input type=”email” id=”validate” width=”50”><span id=”validEmail”></span></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems right on initial inspection. Could go old-school and use alert() or console.log() inside each conditional to see if the conditions are being met. I'm missing how email could ever be "0", so that condition is probably always met. Beyond that, I noticed your HTML at the bottom (inside the div) has the wrong kind of double-quotation marks. Could be as silly as that.

Comment: can u tell me the sample of email address which u r validating

Comment: did u check the error console of ur browser for any javascript errors

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
if(email != 0)
```

with

```
if(email.length != 0)
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't solve the problem. I fixed this code in the past and I can not remember it, and now I can not find the bug :(

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
<div><input type=”email” id=”validate” width=”50”><span id=”validEmail”></span></div>
```

to:

```
<div><input type="email" id="validate" width="50"><span id="validEmail"></span></div>
```

I tested it and it is okay.

Answer (score 0):

I made ur code working.Basically ur Input tag was not correct.
your input tag was

```
   <input type=”email” id=”validate” width=”50”><span id=”validEmail”></span>
```

i changed it to this

```
<input type="email" id="validate" width="50" /><span id="validEmail" ></span>
```

Here's is the working code.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

        function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
            var pattern = new RegExp(/^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@([\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]+$/);

            return pattern.test(emailAddress);
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#validate").keyup(function(){
                var email = $("#validate").val();

                if(email != 0)
                {
                    if(isValidEmailAddress(email))
                    {
                         alert('Valid Email');
                      //  $("#validEmail").css({ "background-image": "url('/myform/logos/validyes.png')" });

                    } else {

                         alert('InValid Email');
                      //  $("#validEmail").css({ "background-image": "url('/myform/logos/validno.png')" });

                    }

                } else {

                    $("#validEmail").css({ "background-image": "none" });

                }
            });
        });

    </script>
        <style>
        #validEmail
        {
            margin-top: 4px;
            margin-left: 9px;
            position: absolute;
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>


    <div><input type="email" id="validate" width="50"><span id="validEmail" /></span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and one moe thing.dont check email validation on keyup event.Guess checking in blur event will be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Change the goofy quotes, to real quotes, add swap out your condition to `email.length > 0`, and then you might as well shorten your code. Too much stuff repeated.

```
function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
  return /^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*@([\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(emailAddress);
}

$(function() {
  $("#validate").keyup(function() {
    var bg = "none";
    var email = $("#validate").val();
    if(email.length > 0) {
      bg = isValidEmailAddress(email) 
           ? "url('/myform/logos/validyes.png')"
           : "url('/myform/logos/validno.png')";
    }
    $("#validEmail").css("background-image", bg);
  });
});
```